# How to correctly handle a disposable Task result?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

I have a scenario where Task1 initializes and returns an `IDisposable` object to be used in a  chained Task2 like this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew<Stream>(() =>
{
    // open and write stream
})
.ContinueWith(prevTask => 
{
    var stream = prevTask.Result;  // possible AggregateException
    // read stream and close it
});
```

The question is: How to dispose of the object correctly? An interesting case could be this: Task1 opens+reads the stream, then an exception occurs, which gets rethrown in Task2, so Task2 won't see the original stream which is still open.

Is there some well known pattern like `using () { ... }` to do it?

Comment: cant you use await keyword ?

Comment: no, it's a .NET4 code

Comment: @metalheart: You can still use async/await with .NET 4, using the Microsoft.Bcl.Async package. You do need a C# 5 compiler though (VS2012 or later).

Comment: "Task1 opens+reads the stream, then an exception occurs" - Task 1 needs to take care of appropriately disposing the stream up until the point when it's completely finished using it and will no longer throw any exceptions. Only at that point should e.g. a flag be set for it to know to no longer Dispose of it.

Comment: Do you actually need two separate `Task`s? Couldn't all the code be placed inside the `StartNew()` lambda?

Comment: I'm with @svick, if you are starting a new Task which will be async, which continue with onto a second Task?

Comment: Because I need the first task to run in the background and the second on the UI thread. I have omitted it for simplicity, but actually I am calling this like this: ContinueWith(...,  TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the pattern you're looking for invoked using the`await` keyword.
The reason the exception is being rethrown is because you're accessing `prevTask.Result`. If you first call `prevTask.IsFaulted`, then you'll be able to react without having the exception rethrown.